# Karate Automation: How to Set Dynamic Path for a URL, from a json data

Tags: karate

From Feature file 1, i am reading the content of a json file and passing it to the serverpost.Feature

```
feature file 1

* def output = read('output.json')
* def result = call read('serverpost.feature') output
```

In feature file 2, i am trying to set the Path as TC_ID and request body as BODY from the json data.

However, i am not able to set the path using the below feature. Please assist

Feature file 2

```
Given path '#(TC_ID)'
Given url 'http://myappurl.com:8080/mytestapp/Servers/Data/uploadServer/'
And request { some: '#(BODY)' }     #### Here i am able to get the BODY data from JSON
When method post
Then status 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'#(foo)'` notation applies only to JSON, XML or the right-hand-side of a `match` statement.

Please use it like a *normal* JS expression:

`Given path TC_ID`

or

`Given path output.TC_ID`

Comment: @Sundan that's a separate question, please upvote and mark as accepted before proceeding, thanks.